# Is there a way to get generics to autocomplete in class declarations in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

If I have an interface like this:

```
public interface GenericDAO<T, PK>
```

and I want to extend that interface in IntelliJ I will use `ctrl-space` at this point:

```
public interface ApplicationDAO extends Generic
```

And I would expect this:

```
public interface ApplicationDAO extends GenericDAO<T, PK>
```

But instead I get

```
public interface ApplicationDAO extends GenericDAO
```

With no indication that generics are available. Is there a way to get it to do this correctly? I am new to IntelliJ so I am stil learning all it's ins and outs.

Comment: This would be invalid code which won't compile. Why do you need IDEA to insert these meaningless generics?

Comment: So that I know they are there. Otherwise, I can end up with some weird compile time issues that I never expected.

Comment: @PeterGromov Generating invalid code isn't really a good argument because other IDEA features are also doing this kind of thing. Live templates is an example of such feature. It is also a good example of how the completion in question could work (with the generic type parameters acting as user-filled variables in live templates).

Comment: @vari it's been a while, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: As far as I know, no.  I am mainly using groovy now, so it's not as big an issue

Answer (score 0):

There's no way currently in IDEA to insert such invalid generics. To know that they're there, you can look at the completion list, they're depicted in the suggestion. You can also enable "Raw use of parameterized class" inspection so that each class use without generics will be highlighted yellow in the editor.

Comment: Any update on this feature? Is there a issue/feature request open which I can vote up? Someone coming from Eclipse could be (is) really disappointed without this.

Comment: There's no such request yet (which suggests this feature isn't in high demand), but you can create one at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Comment: Coming from Eclipse, I'm very surprised it is not a high prio feature request.